# Magento - add feedback with multiple questions and comments

Tags: php, mysql, xml, magento

How to add feedback form in magento? I am new in magento. I'm using 1.8.0.

Comment: Please show your attempted code, results, and expected results or hire a magento developer to do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is a complicated framework and it can be difficult to learn. You haven't given us enough information about your problem for anybody to be of any real help, however, if you are very new to Magento I recommend the following:

Go to: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/
and make an account. There you can find many great modules (many of which are free) that you can search through to find what you are looking for.

Once you've found a module you'd like to try, click "Get Extension" (make sure you choose 2.0) and you will receive a key. Copy that key and go to your Magento site's backend to Configuration > Magento Connect

On that page you will see a place to paste the key and install. Magento will download and install the extension there.

The rest is the fun part-- configuring an extension to meet your needs!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I would like to more clear what we need --It is only a form of general feed back of related services and product. Mostly Questions like this 1. Have you found it easy to navigate around the website and view the products you were looking for? Yes (radio button) No (radio button) If no, why?(comment box) and submit button – Niyaz A. Ansari

Comment: I recommend searching for some jQuery that does it for you if you're savvy with that kind of thing-- otherwise, search MagentoConnect for a solution or, for the easiest (but costliest) solution: hire a freelancer and if you want to pay him or her to teach you, request that service as well.